# how to block url in chrome via android management api

Tags: android-management-api

i am trying this policy json any help appriciaeted

{ "applications": [ { "packageName": "com.google.enterprise.webapp.x6306d4def62b6b3s", "installType": "KIOSK", "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT" }, { "packageName": "com.android.chrome", "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED", "managedConfiguration": { "URLBLacklist": ["*"], "URLWhitelist": ["web.app.url"] }, "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT" } ] }